# Visual studio assembly references

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, assemblies, reference

Is there anyway to localise an external assembly reference? Here's my situation:

I am working on Project A and it contains assembly references from Project B. Now when I release this Project to my client I don't want to have to include the whole of Project B with it. Is there anyway to force it to copy the dll's from Project B onto Project A and use those references? I can do this manually by copying all dll's to local project and re-referencing but just wanted to know if there is an easier way.

Answer (score 1):

you can add reference to project B then from properties window set copy local to true.